# Joining two tables based off of parsed column content

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I am trying to join two tables based off of two columns that have been combined (often imperfectly) into another tables column. I am trying to join the tables so the correct records are associated with each other, so I can compare the `FDebit` and the `Debit` fields.

The `FMEMO` is normally generated by taking the `Num`, then adding a `space`, then adding the `Memo` text. As you can see below, our process is not yet perfect. I would therefore like to match the `Num`, then the `space`, then the first 10 characters of the Memo field to the `FMEMO` field.

I have included code below with sample data. Could you please offer me some suggestions on how to accomplish this?

## Invoices table

MEMO    Num DEBIT
Supplies. Soto Cano 1135    2.25
Suction Hose (1-1/2") by the food   3   74.04
Hose/Tubing:Braided Hose (1") by the food   3   98.72
QP10 Meyers surface pump (60hz) 3   206.27
Cage including f tank, alum parts box and 2 buckets of alum 3   752.03
Cage including valve manifold, F1 & F2  3   3774.08
cage with IBC in it 1135    268.41
Pvc accesories for installation of LWTS.    1175    4.26
Pvc accesories for installation of LWTS.    1175    27.26

## Expenses table

FMEMO   FDebit
Supplies. Soto Cano 41.8    2.25
3 Suction Hose (1-1/2   74.04
3 Hose/Tubing:Braided Hose (1   98.72
3 QP10 Meyers surface pump (60hz) 3970  206.27
3 Cage including f tank, alum parts box and 2 buckets of alum 14474 752.03
3 Cage including valve manifold, F1 & F2 72638  3774.08
3 cage with IBC in it 5166  268.41
1175 Pvc accesories for installation of LWTS. 82.03 4.26
1175 Pvc accesories for installation of LWTS. 524.67    27.26

## Code to replicate:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempExpenses (
FMEMO varchar(Max), FDebit money)

CREATE TABLE #tempInvoices (
MEMO varchar(Max), Num integer, DEBIT money)

INSERT INTO #tempExpenses (FMEMO, FDEBIT) VALUES ('Supplies. Soto Cano 41.8', 2.25)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempExpenses (FMEMO, FDEBIT) VALUES ('3 Suction Hose (1-1/2', 74.04)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempExpenses (FMEMO, FDEBIT) VALUES ('3 Hose/Tubing:Braided Hose (1', 98.72)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempExpenses (FMEMO, FDEBIT) VALUES ('3 QP10 Meyers surface pump (60hz) 3970', 206.27)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempExpenses (FMEMO, FDEBIT) VALUES ('3 Cage including f tank, alum parts box and 2 buckets of alum 14474', 752.03)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempExpenses (FMEMO, FDEBIT) VALUES ('3 Cage including valve manifold, F1 & F2 72638', 3774.08)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempExpenses (FMEMO, FDEBIT) VALUES ('3 cage with IBC in it 5166', 268.41)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempExpenses (FMEMO, FDEBIT) VALUES ('1175 Pvc accesories for installation of LWTS. 82.03', 4.26)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempExpenses (FMEMO, FDEBIT) VALUES ('1175 Pvc accesories for installation of LWTS. 524.67', 27.26)<br/>

INSERT INTO #tempInvoices (MEMO, Num, DEBIT) VALUES ('Supplies. Soto Cano', 1135, 2.25)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempInvoices (MEMO, Num, DEBIT) VALUES ('Suction Hose (1-1/2") by the food', 3, 74.04)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempInvoices (MEMO, Num, DEBIT) VALUES ('Hose/Tubing:Braided Hose (1") by the food', 3, 98.72)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempInvoices (MEMO, Num, DEBIT) VALUES ('QP10 Meyers surface pump (60hz)', 3, 206.27)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempInvoices (MEMO, Num, DEBIT) VALUES ('Cage including f tank, alum parts box and 2 buckets of alum', 3, 752.03)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempInvoices (MEMO, Num, DEBIT) VALUES ('Cage including valve manifold, F1 & F2', 3, 3774.08)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempInvoices (MEMO, Num, DEBIT) VALUES ('cage with IBC in it', 1135, 268.41)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempInvoices (MEMO, Num, DEBIT) VALUES ('Pvc accesories for installation of LWTS.', 1175, 4.26)<br/>
INSERT INTO #tempInvoices (MEMO, Num, DEBIT) VALUES ('Pvc accesories for installation of LWTS.', 1175, 27.26)<br/>

SELECT *
FROM #tempExpenses 

SELECT *
FROM #tempInvoices
```

Comment: I think your time would be better spent fixing your database design. Hopefully whoever decided to set it up that way has been fired already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I really hate myself for producing this TSQL but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM #tempInvoices i
INNER JOIN #tempExpenses e ON CAST(Num as varchar(10)) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(MEMO,1,9-LEN(CAST(NUM as varchar(10)))) = SUBSTRING(FMEMO,1,10)
```

Which concatenates the number and takes so many characters form the field i.e if 3 then 9, if 1111 then 9-4 and joins with the same amount of characters form the other table.

Of course this is a very inefficient and ugly query. I would rather normalize the data in the database (parse clean etc)

Comment: I'd want to fix the database too (it's one of the things I rant about at work...).  Stuff like this makes me want to take baseball bats to the database/code(/occasionally developers).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The query didn't work exactly like I had hoped so I took yours and X-Zero's advice and parsed the data so the joins could be straight-forward. It's working great now. Thanks again!